# All longest Strings

Tags: java, string

I am a beginner in Java. Can you help me please to find all largest strings in given Array.

```
String[] allLongestStrings(String[] a) {
List<String> newArray = new ArrayList<String>();
String max = a[0];
for( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    int sum = max.compareTo(a[i]);
    if( sum < 0) max = a[i];
}
for( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    int b = max.compareTo(a[i]);
    if (b == 0) newArray.add(a[i]);
}
String[] stringArray = newArray.toArray(new String[0]);
return stringArray;
```

}

Comment: You should read [compareTo() documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)). It is not usable for comparing length!

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer:**

```
String[] allLongestStrings(String[] arr) {
    int longest = Arrays.stream(arr)
            .mapToInt(String::length)
            .max()
            .orElse(-1);

    return Arrays.stream(arr)
            .filter(s -> s.length() == longest)
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

**Detailed answer with a couple of ways:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[4];
    arr[0] = "cat";
    arr[1] = "mouse";
    arr[2] = "goose";
    arr[3] = "owl";

    String[] resultJava8 = allLongestStringsJava8(arr);
    String[] resultTraditionalWay = allLongestStringsTraditionalWay(arr);
}

static String[] allLongestStringsJava8(String[] arr) {
    int longest = Arrays.stream(arr)
            .mapToInt(String::length)
            .max()
            .orElse(-1);

    return Arrays.stream(arr)
            .filter(s -> s.length() == longest)
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}

static String[] allLongestStringsTraditionalWay(String[] arr) {
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>(); //or use a LinkedList if there can be same strings
    int longestLength = 0;
    for (String s : arr) {
        if (s.length() < longestLength)
            continue;
        if (s.length() > longestLength)
            result.clear();
        result.add(s);
        longestLength = s.length();
    }
    return result.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = new String[] {"ab", "abc", "a", "def"};
        int maxLength = Arrays.stream(a).max(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.length())).get().length();
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(a).filter(str -> str.length() == maxLength).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
```

Output:

```
[abc, def]
```

Comment: According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator- this will return an Optional and not *all* longest strings as asked in the question

Comment: @Kartik If you have a look at the method signature, a String[] is returned. So my assumption is, if the input is e.g. ["cat", "mouse", "goose"], then ["mouse", "goose"] should be returned.

Comment: @Gernot Yup, sorry, realised it while I was typing. Updated my answer.

Comment: My bad. Updated my answer.